# combine 2 files with AWK based last colums

Tags: awk

i have two files

```
file1
-------------------------------
1      a      t      p      b
2      b      c      f      a
3      d      y      u      b
2      b      c      f      a
2      u      g      t      c
2      b      j      h      c

file2
--------------------------------
1   a   b
2   p   c
3   n   a
4   4   a
```

i want combine these 2 files based last columns (column 5 of file1 and column 3 of file2) using awk

```
result
----------------------------------------------
1      a      t      p     1   a   b
2      b      c      f     3   n   a
2      b      c      f     4   4   a
3      d      y      u     1   a   b
2      b      c      f     3   n   a
2      b      c      f     4   4   a
2      u      g      t     2   p   c
2      b      j      h     2   p   c
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you explain what a column is, rather than expecting us to decipher it?

Comment: +1, this is actually an interesting question. the file2 is abit tricky.. two same "a" at column 3. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the very beginning, I didn't see the duplicated "a" in file2, I thought it would be solved with normal array matching. ... now it works.

an awk onliner:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3"_"NR]=$0;next;}{for(x in a){if(x~"^"$5) print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[x];}}' f2.txt f1.txt
```

**test**

```
kent$  head *.txt  
==> f1.txt <==
1      a      t      p      b
2      b      c      f      a
3      d      y      u      b
2      b      c      f      a
2      u      g      t      c
2      b      j      h      c

==> f2.txt <==
1   a   b
2   p   c
3   n   a
4   4   a

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3"_"NR]=$0;next;}{for(x in a){if(x~"^"$5) print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[x];}}' f2.txt f1.txt 
1 a t p 1   a   b
2 b c f 3   n   a
2 b c f 4   4   a
3 d y u 1   a   b
2 b c f 3   n   a
2 b c f 4   4   a
2 u g t 2   p   c
2 b j h 2   p   c
```

note, the output format was not sexy, but it would be acceptable if pipe it to `column -t`

Comment: it works fine but as i am rookie in awk can you please tell me what "if(x~"^"$5)" is doing? and what is the meaning of array a[$3"_"NR]?

Comment: @mohammadreshad `~` operation is doing regex matching. `a[$3"_"NR]` is declaring an array to store file2 data.

Answer (score 0):

Other way assuming files have no headers:

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {
        f2[ $NF ] = f2[ $NF ] ? f2[ $NF ] SUBSEP $0 : $0;
        next;
    }

    FNR < NR {
        if ( $NF in f2 ) {
            split( f2[ $NF ], a, SUBSEP );
            len = length( a );
            for ( i = 1; i <= len; i++ ) {
                $NF = a[ i ];       
            }
        }
        printf "%s\n", $0;
    }
' file2 file1 | column -t
```

It yields:

```
1  a  t  p  1  a  b
2  b  c  f  3  n  a
2  b  c  f  4  4  a
3  d  y  u  1  a  b
2  b  c  f  3  n  a
2  b  c  f  4  4  a
2  u  g  t  2  p  c
2  b  j  h  2  p  c
```

Comment: it gives me "fatal error: attemp to use array 'a' in scalar context"!

Comment: @mohammadreshad: Which version of `awk` do you use?

Answer (score 0):

A bit easier in a language that supports arbitrary data structures (list of lists). Here's ruby

```ruby
# read "file2" and group by the last field
file2 = File .foreach('file2') .map(&:split) .group_by {|fields| fields[-1]}

# process file1
File .foreach('file1') .map(&:split) .each do |fields|
  file2[fields[-1]] .each do |fields2|
    puts (fields[0..-2] + fields2).join(" ")
  end 
end
```

outputs

```
1 a t p 1 a b
2 b c f 3 n a
2 b c f 4 4 a
3 d y u 1 a b
2 b c f 3 n a
2 b c f 4 4 a
2 u g t 2 p c
2 b j h 2 p c
```